# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

guys i am working on laravel project (i am beginner in laravel ) my role in this project is making the views and injecting the data ... while i am trying to inject Post in my view i got this error "Trying to get property of non-object "  i am searching on the internet and some says that "may be the object returns null but i checked all the data comes from the object in the Controller and i found data by dd($post);"

here's the HomeController method that returns the post object

```
public function index()
        {
            $sliders = Slider::take(5)->get();

            $post = Post::latest()->first();

            $users = User::subscribed()->take(12)->get()->shuffle();

        return view('frontend.pages.home2', compact('sliders', 'sliders', 'users', 'post'))->with('success',' success test');
        }
```

and this is what i am trying to do in the view

```
             @foreach($post as $pos)
                   <p  class="text-primary col-lg-4 col-md-4 sliderParagraph menuDirection">

                      {{$pos->body_ar}}
                    </p>
                @endforeach

            <p  class="text-primary col-lg-4 col-md-4 sliderParagraph menuDirection">
        some text here to be displayed 
                        <br>
                        <button  type="button" class=" btn btn-primary">more</button>
                    </p>
                    <img   class="nlpimage img-responsive " src="images/nnn.jpg">
                </div>
```

and here's the Post.php class

```
        namespace App\Src;

        use App\Core\Traits\LocaleTrait;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
        use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

        class Post extends Model
        {

            use Notifiable, LocaleTrait;

            public $localeStrings = ['title', 'body'];
            public $guarded = [];

            public function user()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
            }

            public function gallery()
            {
                return $this->morphMany(Gallery::class, 'galleryable');
            }

        }
```

and the post table in the DB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8BGc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `foreach`, because you are just passing one **post** instance to the view:

```
<p  class="text-primary col-lg-4 col-md-4 sliderParagraph menuDirection">

{{$post->body_ar}}
</p>
```

If you want to display more post, change to controller, to get more results (and use the foreach in your template, because now its an array):

```
$post = Post::latest()->take(3)->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want to pass 3 posts ... its a post slider ... and when i typed {{$post->body_ar}} it returns one ...and i need the latest 3 post ...how can i do it in blade

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$post = Post::latest()->first();
```

Reason: If the data returned is empty or mis-matched then alone you will be  getting this error.

> If you pass one row of data alone to the blade the `foreach()` seems to be an invalid option over there.

And that is the reason you will be getting this error over there.

**Your blade will look like:**

```
<p  class="text-primary col-lg-4 col-md-4 sliderParagraph menuDirection">
{{$post->body_ar}}
</p>
<p  class="text-primary col-lg-4 col-md-4 sliderParagraph menuDirection">
some text here to be displayed 
<br>
<button  type="button" class=" btn btn-primary">more</button>
</p>
<img   class="nlpimage img-responsive " src="images/nnn.jpg">
</div>
```

**Note:** For passing of single value over to the blade you must not use `foreach()`. If it an array of values you can use foreach to iterate and then print the value over there.

Comment: thanks for your reply it works but for only one post and i need to retrieve the latest 3 posts how can i do it in blade ?